# change column name using index

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
         'one': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'one': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
         'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I have bigger dataframe with multiple columns of having same name .
I want to change the column name from number of column as in r.
e.g. `colnames(df)[2]='two'`
I want to change second column name 'one' to 'two' .I want to do 
that in python .

Comment: You dictionary is broken.

Comment: Sorry , Stephen Rauch for that . Thank you for your consideration .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpliest is assign new columns names by `np.arange` or `range`:

```
#valid dictionary have unique keys
d = {
         'one1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'one2': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
         'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.columns = ['one'] * 2 + ['three']
print (df)
   one  one three
0    1    9     a
1    2    8     b
2    3    7     c
3    4    6     d
4    5    5     e

df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
#alternative
#df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  9  a
1  2  8  b
2  3  7  c
3  4  6  d
4  5  5  e
```

Then select by name:

```
print (df[1])
0    9
1    8
2    7
3    6
4    5
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```